# not able to click on following link using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on following link using `selenium webdriver`:

```
<center>
  <a class="xyz" style="" href="/Folder">My Folders</a>
  <span></span>
</center>
```

I am using the code:

```
abhiFX.findElement(By.partialLinkText("My Folders")).click();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please, when you present a particular problem, ask a specific question.  It may seem obvious to you what the question is, but it might not be to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use xpath instead:

```
public void clickElement() {

    try {
        WebElement element = abhiFX.findElement(
            By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'My Folders')]"));
        element.click();
    } catch (InvalidSelectorException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("[FAIL] Click Element: Xpath is invalid.");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(
                "[FAIL] Click Element: Unable to locate element");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I see these potential problems:

1. Are you sure that your HTML 'works' at all if **you** load the page in a browser and click on the link? What's the expected result of the click?
2. Is your driver `abhiFX` initialized properly? Does `.click()` on other elements work well?